# Displaying dynamic images using php

Tags: php, image

I am trying to use php to display images based on the id of the item. This is for an ecommerce store, I am having difficulty figuring it out however. This is the php I have:

```
     <?php 
     $product_list = "";
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC");
     $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
     if ($productCount > 0) {
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $pid = $row['id'];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $product_list .= "HERE IS WHERE THE IMAGE  &nbsp; <strong>$product_name</strong> - $$price - <em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br />";
         }
     } else {
         $product_list = "You have no products listed in your store yet";
     }
?>
```

In theory, I was trying to add, where the text HERE IS WHERE THE IMAGE is to use:

```
    <img src='../inventory_images/$pid.jpg' />
```

However this and other variations that I tried did not work. How the image is uploaded is that the variable "$pid" is the id of the product, and the .jpg ending is added, here is the code to explain that:

```
    $pid = mysql_insert_id();
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
```

So theoretically simply by having the product id I can get the image out using $pid... that just isn't working. Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you confirm that the directory where the images are kept is accessible by using the ../ shortcut? Have you also tried putting that path into a browser to see if the image loads?

Comment: Check the HTML that your code is outputting to make sure that it's what you think it's outputting - you're using a relative link for the image, for one thing, so maybe it's looking in the wrong directory?

Comment: Did you try echoing the line variable $product_list to see what's contained in the <img> tag? If so, what is it?

Comment: I just looked in the folder and the test image isn't there, so I guess it isn't uploading the way it should. Everything else is in the database, and correctly so. So the error must be in that last bit of php in the question itself, let me try to figure out what that error is, but help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper it is a box that has the words "Image" in it, but no actual image.

Comment: So it means it cannot find the image then. Right click the image and check the "image url", image "src", or hit the "inspect element" button to see the entire <img> tag and the exact image it's trying to load.

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper the image is correct, <img src="../inventory_images/2.jpg"/> the image just doesn't exist, so the issue is that when I upload the image, it isn't making it into the file. The code that should handle that is:

` $pid = mysql_insert_id();`
    `$newname = "$pid.jpg";`
    `move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");`

Comment: Ok sorry haha! Dumb question, did you check if the folder has the right permissions? Sometimes I forget. Is the path "../inventory_images.." relative to the script being executed? And I supposed you checked $_FILES to see its content since you did not get any error? One last suggestion, is your form set to enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: The form is set to multipart/form-data, tbh I suck at php and have no idea how to check $_FILES, I am learning as I go via tutorials, that is what this is from. I'm not sure how to check permissions. I do understand how to set them, but the product_images directory is in the root directory, the script is inside the admin directory which is in the root directory.

Comment: Ok, so paths are ok, I'm pretty sure it's a permission problem, I'll follow with your other comments via Luke to see how you have set the permissions. We might need to know what ftp software you are using to tell you how to check permissions though.

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper thanks :) I know how to set permissions, I'm just a bit weak in the understanding of how permissions affect everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an error in your output as well, could you try to replace that line:

```
$product_list .= "HERE IS WHERE THE IMAGE  &nbsp; <strong>$product_name</strong> - $$price - <em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br />";
```

With that line:

```
$product_list .= "HERE IS WHERE THE IMAGE  &nbsp; <strong>$product_name</strong> - \$$price - <em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$pid'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$pid'>delete</a><br />";
```

Comment: Everything else is outputting correctly,can I ask what difference the "\" should make?

Comment: It's not only that, it's also the $id variable instead of $pid, is that normal? $$price would also be a variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php so the backslash says to ignore the first dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you discovered that your image was not actually there so I thought I'd share this with you.  You can check if this file exists quite easily:

```
if (file_exists ('../inventory_images/' . $pid . '.jpg')) {
  $product_image = '<img src="../inventory_images/' . $pid . '.jpg">';
} else {
  $product_image = '<img src="../inventory_images/image_not_found.jpg">';
}
```

Then simply use that $product_image variable in your $product_list where you need it.  You could also modify the else statement and work in some error handling (update a field in a DB, send you an email, etc...).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great and I really appreciate it, but at the moment I'm stuck on how to actually get it to the folder, I'm not seeing what is wrong with the code that is supposed to upload the image to that file. If you could assist with that as well, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No problem.  Are you confident that your reference to the path is correct?  In other words, does the script your running have write access to '../inventory_images/' ?

Comment: I have tried direct and relative paths, the path is correct in both formats.

Comment: How would I know if it had write access? How do I tell?

Comment: Looked at your code again and you'll definitely want to use the following:

`if (move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname")) { echo 'file uploaded successfully'; } else { echo '<span style="color: #f00";>ERROR UPLOADING FILE!</span>'; }`

Comment: For the move_uploaded_file function to work your script must have write access to the directory that it is trying to write to.  Have you set the permissions of the directory using an FTP client or by other means?

Comment: the directory permissions are 755, but the files are all 644. I'll try this script as well, thanks :)

Comment: Set the `../inventory_images/` to 777 and try it again (just to test - you don't want to leave a directory as 777 if you can avoid it).

Comment: with that script it said "error uploading file", with my limited knowledge I don't see an error with the script, so the only thing else I can think of is permissions like you said, but for editing permissions, should I edit the images directory, or the file with the script?

Comment: Put this on top of your script, it should report all errors and might give you more info:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Undefined variable:

`$product_list .= "<img src='../inventory_images/$pid.jpg' />  &nbsp; <strong>$product_name</strong> - $$price - <em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br />";`

Comment: I had error reporting in before, i think I deleted it, don't remember doing that though. But before trying to output images there were no errors.

Comment: You would only need to set the images directory itself with the new permissions.  I should have expanded that code I gave you to include the error output.  You can get by adding this to the `else {...}` section of the code I gave you: `echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['fileField']['error'];`

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: fileField in /home/ssdotcom/public_html/graphic-shack.com/admin/inventory_list.php on line 66
ERROR UPLOADING FILE!
Notice: Undefined index: fileField in /home/ssdotcom/public_html/graphic-shack.com/admin/inventory_list.php on line 67
 Error: 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ssdotcom/public_html/graphic-shack.com/admin/inventory_list.php:66) in /home/ssdotcom/public_html/graphic-shack.com/admin/inventory_list.php on line 68

Comment: I suspected that the name "fileField" may have been the problem.  In the form that submits to that PHP script you'll need to change the "name" of the "input" that has a type "file" to "fileField".  In other words, they have to match.

Comment: I changed the part of the form (name, type, id) where it said file to fileField but it is still saying fileField is undefined.

Comment: `name` and `id` should be `fileField` but `type` needs to remain `file`.

Comment: it is still saying fileField is undefined

Comment: Seeing what's in your $_FILES variable will help, can you tell us what's displayed with var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: sorry, what does that mean and where do I put it?

Comment: Right above your "move_uploaded_file", this line will output in the browser the content of the "$_FILES" variable and might help debug, you can post it here. I have to go now, I hope the others will be able to help

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an on-call debugging service.